.NET MAUI Community Toolkit MVVM update from another thread
I am using the .NET MAUI Community Toolkit MVVM, and binding to elements from a view model.
If I now need to update the GUI by updating a variable in model view (ObservableObject), what will be the best/right/easiest way to do it using .NET MAUI Community Toolkit MVVM?
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>

or
private readonly IDispatcher

or
BindableObject.Dispatcher.Dispatch()

or something else?
Normally I use:
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread

Thanks in advance

If you are binding to the ModelView properties, none of them is required. Simply, set the value from another thread and the binding engine will take care of that.

See https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/7518
